# Obsolete cryptography warning from Browser

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl

I have started a Windows Server with Apache 2.4 and SSL. When I connect with https://www.example.com and click on green lock, i have message:

> Your connection to website is encrypted with obsolete cryptography

Any advice, please?

Below is ***`ssl.conf`***:

```
    #
    # This is the Apache server configuration file providing SSL support.
    # It contains the configuration directives to instruct the server how to
    # serve pages over an https connection. For detailed information about these 
    # directives see <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html>
    # 
    # Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
    # what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
    # consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
    #
    # Required modules: mod_log_config, mod_setenvif, mod_ssl,
    #          socache_shmcb_module (for default value of SSLSessionCache)

    #
    # Pseudo Random Number Generator (PRNG):
    # Configure one or more sources to seed the PRNG of the SSL library.
    # The seed data should be of good random quality.
    # WARNING! On some platforms /dev/random blocks if not enough entropy
    # is available. This means you then cannot use the /dev/random device
    # because it would lead to very long connection times (as long as
    # it requires to make more entropy available). But usually those
    # platforms additionally provide a /dev/urandom device which doesn't
    # block. So, if available, use this one instead. Read the mod_ssl User
    # Manual for more details.
    #
    #SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/random  512
    #SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom 512

    #
    # When we also provide SSL we have to listen to the 
    # standard HTTP port (see above) and to the HTTPS port
    #
    Listen 443

    ##
    ##  SSL Global Context
    ##
    ##  All SSL configuration in this context applies both to
    ##  the main server and all SSL-enabled virtual hosts.
    ##

    #   SSL Cipher Suite:
    #   List the ciphers that the client is permitted to negotiate.
    #   See the mod_ssl documentation for a complete list.
    #SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5


    #   Speed-optimized SSL Cipher configuration:
    #   If speed is your main concern (on busy HTTPS servers e.g.),
    #   you might want to force clients to specific, performance
    #   optimized ciphers. In this case, prepend those ciphers
    #   to the SSLCipherSuite list, and enable SSLHonorCipherOrder.
    #   Caveat: by giving precedence to RC4-SHA and AES128-SHA
    #   (as in the example below), most connections will no longer
    #   have perfect forward secrecy - if the server's key is
    #   compromised, captures of past or future traffic must be
    #   considered compromised, too.
    SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA:HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
    #SSLHonorCipherOrder on 

    #   Pass Phrase Dialog:
    #   Configure the pass phrase gathering process.
    #   The filtering dialog program (`builtin' is an internal
    #   terminal dialog) has to provide the pass phrase on stdout.
    SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

    #   Inter-Process Session Cache:
    #   Configure the SSL Session Cache: First the mechanism 
    #   to use and second the expiring timeout (in seconds).
    #SSLSessionCache         "dbm:c:/Apache24/logs/ssl_scache"

    # Estes 2 estavam ativos
    #SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:c:/Apache24/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
    #SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

    #   OCSP Stapling (requires OpenSSL 0.9.8h or later)
    #
    #   This feature is disabled by default and requires at least
    #   the two directives SSLUseStapling and SSLStaplingCache.
    #   Refer to the documentation on OCSP Stapling in the SSL/TLS
    #   How-To for more information.
    #
    #   Enable stapling for all SSL-enabled servers:
    #SSLUseStapling On

    #   Define a relatively small cache for OCSP Stapling using
    #   the same mechanism that is used for the SSL session cache
    #   above.  If stapling is used with more than a few certificates,
    #   the size may need to be increased.  (AH01929 will be logged.)
    #SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:c:/Apache24/logs/ssl_stapling(32768)"

    #   Seconds before valid OCSP responses are expired from the cache
    #SSLStaplingStandardCacheTimeout 3600

    #   Seconds before invalid OCSP responses are expired from the cache
    #SSLStaplingErrorCacheTimeout 600

    ##
    ## SSL Virtual Host Context
    ##

    <VirtualHost *:443>

    #   General setup for the virtual host
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs"
    ServerName www.xxx.com:443
    ServerAdmin webmaster@xxx.com
    ErrorLog "c:/Apache24/logs/error.log"
    TransferLog "c:/Apache24/logs/access.log"

    #   SSL Engine Switch:
    #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
    SSLEngine on


    #   Server Certificate:
    #   Point SSLCertificateFile at a PEM encoded certificate.  If
    #   the certificate is encrypted, then you will be prompted for a
    #   pass phrase.  Note that a kill -HUP will prompt again.  Keep
    #   in mind that if you have both an RSA and a DSA certificate you
    #   can configure both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA
    #   ciphers, etc.)
    #   Some ECC cipher suites (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4492.txt)
    #   require an ECC certificate which can also be configured in
    #   parallel.
    SSLCertificateFile "c:/Apache24/conf/aws-101.crt"
    #SSLCertificateFile "c:/Apache24/conf/server-dsa.crt"
    #SSLCertificateFile "c:/Apache24/conf/server-ecc.crt"

    #   Server Private Key:
    #   If the key is not combined with the certificate, use this
    #   directive to point at the key file.  Keep in mind that if
    #   you've both a RSA and a DSA private key you can configure
    #   both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA ciphers, etc.)
    #   ECC keys, when in use, can also be configured in parallel
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/Apache24/conf/aws-101.key"

    #   Server Certificate Chain:
    #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
    #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
    #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
    #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
    #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
    #   certificate for convenience.
    SSLCertificateChainFile "c:/Apache24/conf/aws-101_ca_bundle.crt"

    #   Certificate Authority (CA):
    #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
    #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
    #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
    #   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
    #         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
    #         Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
    #SSLCACertificatePath "c:/Apache24/conf/aws-101_ca_bundle.crt"
    #SSLCACertificateFile "c:/Apache24/conf/aws-101_ca_bundle.crt"

    #   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
    #   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
    #   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
    #   of them (file must be PEM encoded).
    #   The CRL checking mode needs to be configured explicitly
    #   through SSLCARevocationCheck (defaults to "none" otherwise).
    #   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
    #         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
    #         Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
    #SSLCARevocationPath "c:/Apache24/conf/ssl.crl"
    #SSLCARevocationFile "c:/Apache24/conf/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl"
    #SSLCARevocationCheck chain

    #   Client Authentication (Type):
    #   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
    #   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
    #   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
    #   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
    #SSLVerifyClient require
    #SSLVerifyDepth  10

    #   TLS-SRP mutual authentication:
    #   Enable TLS-SRP and set the path to the OpenSSL SRP verifier
    #   file (containing login information for SRP user accounts). 
    #   Requires OpenSSL 1.0.1 or newer. See the mod_ssl FAQ for
    #   detailed instructions on creating this file. Example:
    #   "openssl srp -srpvfile c:/Apache24/conf/passwd.srpv -add username"
    #SSLSRPVerifierFile "c:/Apache24/conf/passwd.srpv"

    #   Access Control:
    #   With SSLRequire you can do per-directory access control based
    #   on arbitrary complex boolean expressions containing server
    #   variable checks and other lookup directives.  The syntax is a
    #   mixture between C and Perl.  See the mod_ssl documentation
    #   for more details.
    #<Location />
    #SSLRequire (    %{SSL_CIPHER} !~ m/^(EXP|NULL)/ \
    #            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "Snake Oil, Ltd." \
    #            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} in {"Staff", "CA", "Dev"} \
    #            and %{TIME_WDAY} >= 1 and %{TIME_WDAY} <= 5 \
    #            and %{TIME_HOUR} >= 8 and %{TIME_HOUR} <= 20       ) \
    #           or %{REMOTE_ADDR} =~ m/^192\.76\.162\.[0-9]+$/
    #</Location>

    #   SSL Engine Options:
    #   Set various options for the SSL engine.
    #   o FakeBasicAuth:
    #     Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
    #     the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
    #     user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
    #     Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
    #     file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
    #   o ExportCertData:
    #     This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
    #     SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
    #     server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
    #     authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
    #     into CGI scripts.
    #   o StdEnvVars:
    #     This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
    #     Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
    #     because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
    #     useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
    #     exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
    #   o StrictRequire:
    #     This denies access when "SSLRequireSSL" or "SSLRequire" applied even
    #     under a "Satisfy any" situation, i.e. when it applies access is denied
    #     and no other module can change it.
    #   o OptRenegotiate:
    #     This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
    #     directives are used in per-directory context. 
    #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    #   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
    #   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
    #   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
    #   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
    #   approach you can use one of the following variables:
    #   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
    #     This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
    #     SSL close notify alert is sent or allowed to be received.  This violates
    #     the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
    #     this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
    #     mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
    #   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
    #     This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
    #     SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
    #     alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
    #     practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
    #     this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
    #     works correctly. 
    #   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
    #   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
    #   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
    #   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
    #   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
    #   "force-response-1.0" for this.
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    #   Per-Server Logging:
    #   The home of a custom SSL log file. Use this when you want a
    #   compact non-error SSL logfile on a virtual host basis.
    CustomLog "c:/Apache24/logs/ssl_request.log" \
              "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: maybe this can be work? http://tecadmin.net/enable-tls-on-windows-server-and-iis/

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 7):

From https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/education/tls#TOC-Deprecation-of-TLS-Features-Algorithms-in-Chrome

> **Obsolete Cipher Suites**
>
> You may see:
>
> “Your connection to example.com is encrypted with obsolete
>   cryptography.”
>
> This means that the connection to the current website is using an
>   outdated cipher suite (which Chrome still allows if the server insists
>   on it).
>
> In order for the message to indicate “modern cryptography”, the
>   connection should use forward secrecy and either AES-GCM or
>   CHACHA20_POLY1305. Other cipher suites are known to have weaknesses.
>   Most servers will wish to negotiate
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256.

All this boils down to the following lines in your configuration, that determine which cipher suites are supported and prioritized for connections with clients.

```
SSLProtocol
SSLCipherSuite
SSLHonorCipherOrder
```

Per https://certsimple.com/blog/chrome-outdated-cryptography and https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/, you may want to give this a try:

```
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
```

See also:

[1] https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/ - Suggests security configurations

[2] https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html -- Test your server's SSL configuration

Answer (score 3):

Visit http://ssllabs.com and verify your site as per the instructions. They will then tell you what is wrong and also how to fix it. Almost certainly you will have to remove the RC4 suites, but the site willl tell you, don't rely on me.

Comment: Related, be careful of the SSL Labs report. On occasion, it will produce spurious findings. You might end up trying to fix problems that don't exist.

Answer (score 3):

> Your connection to website is encrypted with obsolete cryptography...
>   Any advice, please?

The `SSLCipherSuite` of  `HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5` is not bad. You should change it to `HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!RC4` because `MEDIUM` is weak and RC4 is weak/wounded.

The browsers are moving to flag/warn on RC4 use. See, for example, [Connection information claims RC4 is "high grade"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=947149)

---

*If* you want to only use ephemeral or temporary Diffie-Hellman keys (which you should), then you should remove RSA key transport, too:

```
SSLCipherSuite  HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!MD5:!RC4
```

---

And as Anand pointed out, you should disable SSLv2 and SSLv3:

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
```

---

Related, you can get a list of the cipher suites enabled based on the string you are using with the `openssl ciphers` command. Because you are not using DSS, SRP or PSK, you can even include `!DSS:!DSA:!SRP:!PSK` in the string.

```
$ openssl ciphers -v 'HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!MD5:!RC4:!DSS:!DSA:!SRP:!PSK'
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
```

Comment: +1 because its useful, but `SSLCipherSuite  HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!MD5:!RC4` gives errors in the browser. Perhaps an old server with different standards of 'HIGH' ?

Comment: `HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!RC4` worked in all browsers, and chrome then uses RSA for key transport. Perhaps my servers openssl doesn't support the right non-RSA key transport.