# OpenSSL certificate generation for DHE exchange

Tags: c++, openssl, x509

I'm a beginner in the matter of security and OpenSSL. My objective is to programatically generate a certificate that passes the "obsolete" shaming that Chrome does. The certificates I used to generate used `AES_128_GCM` with `RSA` even though I tried setting the cipher list to `kEECDH:kEDH:!ADH:AES256-SHA256` and the server context uses `SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_2_server_method());`.

Based on the example from [the documentation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Diffie_Hellman) I tried the following :

```
X509 *x = NULL;
EVP_PKEY *pk = NULL;
EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx = NULL;
EVP_PKEY *params = NULL;

if(NULL == (params = EVP_PKEY_new()))
    goto err;

if(1 != EVP_PKEY_set1_DH(params, DH_get_2048_256()))
    goto err;

if(!(ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(params, NULL)))
    goto err;

if(!EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(ctx))
    goto err;

if(!EVP_PKEY_keygen(ctx, &pk))
    goto err;

if ((x=X509_new()) == NULL)
    goto err;

X509_set_version(x,2);
X509_set_pubkey(x,pk);

//... (setting the issuer, subject, etc)

//Here is where it fails
if (!X509_sign(x,pk,EVP_sha256()))
    goto err;
```

The same code for `RSA` instead of `DH` works. The error that `X509_sign` gives is `EVP_PKEY_sign_init operation not supported for this keytype`.

What could I do? I would prefer the connection to use `ECDHE` but I have no idea how to set that up. I need this to be secure within reason but my knowledge of security is really limited. I am working on it though. Any help would be appreciated but please provide code with your answer (not command-line generation).

Comment: Related, [Obsolete cryptography warning from Browser](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30270788). One of the answers explains the warning you may be getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My objective is to programatically generate a certificate that passes the "obsolete" shaming that Chrome does...
>   What could I do? I would prefer the connection to use ECDHE but I have no idea how to set that up....
>   I tried setting the cipher list to `kEECDH:kEDH:!ADH:AES256-SHA256`...

Usually, `HIGH:!aNULL:!RC4:!MD5` is enough. Since you want to use the ephemeral key exchanges (whihc is a good thing), you should remove RSA key transport, too: `HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!RC4:!MD5`.

---

> Based on the example from the documentation...

Also see [SSL/TLS Client](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on the OpenSSL wiki. Its a client, but it shows you how to set up a context.

Because its a server, you will also probably want context options like [SSL_OP_SAFARI_ECDHE_ECDSA_BUG](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL_OP_SAFARI_ECDHE_ECDSA_BUG).

---

> OpenSSL certificate generation for DHE exchange

Just about any certificate will do. It can be a RSA key, an DSS key or an ECDSA key. The key in the certificate will be used to sign server messages (some hand waiving), so its used for server authentication.

Ephemeral key exchanges are different. You ensure that with [`SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list.html) and the cipher suite string.

---

Since you are not using cipher suites like SRP and PSK you can remove them too. RSA still shows up, but its for server authentication, and not key transport:

```
$ openssl ciphers -v 'HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!RC4:!MD5:!3DES:!DSS:!DSA:!SRP:!PSK'
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
```

Comment: Ok. I've generated the certificates and signed them with RSA 2048 bit keys as before. All OpenSSL functions work and don't return errors but I'm not getting any content. Although that might be caused by something else. As soon as I'll get this working I'll probably accept your answer.