# SSL handshake faillure with node.js server

Tags: node.js, https, socket.io, openssl, bitnami

I'm currently trying to create a secure connection with socket.io, and I really can't achieve that for now. Trying to check if my certificates are rights, I tried to create a basic https server in nodeJS.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var certDir = "/path/to/the/certificates/cert-test/";
require("https").createServer(
{
    key  : fs.readFileSync(certDir + 'srv.key'),
    cert : fs.readFileSync(certDir + 'crt.pem'),
},
function(request, response){
    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World!\n");
    response.end();
}).listen(8082).on('clientError', function(e){
    console.log(e);
});
```

The equivalent with http works fine, but it's impossible to make this one work. I upgraded the node version to v0.12.4, npm to 2.11.0, https is 1.0.0 (and for further enquiries, socket.io is 1.3.5). The server is on AWS , with a bitnami instance, Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS, kernel version 3.2.0-84-virtual and OpenSSL is 1.0.1i.

I try to reach the server through https://node.foobar.com:8082 (both in my browser and with curl), but I never achieve a proper handshake.

The server detects the following errors :

- [Error: 3074971392:error:1408A0C1:SSL
  routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:no shared
  cipher:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_srvr.c:1389: ]
- [Error: 3074971392:error:140A1175:SSL
  routines:SSL_BYTES_TO_CIPHER_LIST:inappropriate
  fallback:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/ssl_lib.c:1481: ]

I tried to check the ciphers available on the server and the ones available on my computer, and there are many matches. So guys, I'm really out of ideas, and I would appreciate some help...

***EDIT***

output for `openssl x509 -in crt.pem -inform PEM -text -noout` :

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            af:b7:19:35:7b:0e:87:38
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=Arizona, L=Scottsdale, O=GoDaddy.com, Inc.,    OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate     Authority - G2
        Validity
            Not Before: Jan  6 10:11:41 2015 GMT
            Not After : Jan 25 08:15:28 2016 GMT
        Subject: OU=Domain Control Validated, CN=node.foobar.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            Public-Key: (2048 bit)
            Modulus:
                00:ce:93:8c:6a:0a:54:d8:b8:02:94:0d:d4:23:98:
                80:98:5e:42:fb:b2:4a:f7:62:68:82:42:32:dc:6f:
                5d:02:3a:b8:34:7c:9f:1c:e6:83:94:a3:1a:1e:25:
                aa:58:69:4b:4d:76:8e:07:73:09:d3:6a:20:65:ad:
                40:f5:a4:75:fa:51:79:af:94:1d:c3:39:c0:d4:70:
                e0:f0:61:e7:26:d8:78:b8:58:7e:0e:85:22:a2:83:
                09:69:85:f6:3e:b1:de:80:71:07:88:d8:9f:f9:6a:
                8b:d4:ad:61:bc:c2:bb:98:6c:36:71:d8:20:3f:d1:
                d4:d8:0e:91:d7:eb:42:3f:f3:98:97:fa:c4:cb:78:
                04:c2:ef:12:ba:a5:cf:cd:05:44:ad:a1:cc:ff:04:
                b9:e1:74:ab:09:8a:58:1b:11:e6:f9:8f:28:c2:39:
                3d:71:1e:e4:e2:e4:a4:f7:45:94:04:f2:4a:fc:62:
                ab:b5:9a:18:56:e8:40:4d:12:17:a7:26:07:54:db:
                5b:87:99:56:9e:5c:94:28:0d:6c:29:9d:06:56:3b:
                5e:c2:1f:6b:1f:6a:90:c2:97:24:77:63:32:26:f5:
                25:d6:02:73:61:6b:69:20:39:a7:be:af:51:27:c5:
                a5:b4:a4:1f:e2:36:fc:15:25:30:fe:08:8f:0a:12:
                5f:c9
            Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:FALSE
        X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
            TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
        X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

            Full Name:
              URI:http://crl.godaddy.com/gdig2s1-87.crl

        X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
            Policy: 2.16.840.1.114413.1.7.23.1
              CPS: http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/

        Authority Information Access: 
            OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.godaddy.com/
            CA Issuers - URI:http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/gdig2.crt

        X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
            keyid:40:C2:BD:27:8E:CC:34:83:30:A2:33:D7:FB:6C:B3:F0:B4:2C:80:CE

        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
            DNS:foobar.com, DNS:www.foobar.com, DNS:www.foo.bar.com
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
            70:FE:A0:B4:00:2E:14:98:B8:CA:BF:C8:63:A7:23:63:7C:FA:48:82
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
     70:b7:dd:2b:ed:b9:7b:4e:4d:b1:13:26:7b:5d:f4:10:1f:28:
     a4:b8:f5:99:4e:ee:34:56:b1:eb:06:19:d8:14:c8:28:44:fe:
     63:f1:2e:58:73:c7:22:57:1a:4f:2c:00:ef:2b:f8:c6:52:09:
     71:1a:68:00:35:a0:f8:df:57:c5:98:f8:43:68:ba:b5:ff:3e:
     e1:a5:ad:6a:85:64:dd:40:72:d1:9d:04:61:54:cc:7c:92:c4:
     b3:68:6a:77:32:1b:49:ea:6c:7e:28:c7:67:ce:1d:ed:29:49:
     d6:9c:76:4d:a3:f1:a5:f5:0a:0a:92:72:7e:0a:1a:22:43:32:
     18:9f:3f:fe:62:e0:57:ee:92:9d:fb:5f:bd:4b:c9:c4:1d:ba:
     cb:0d:3c:b9:00:2f:79:fc:5d:cd:df:9e:d7:c9:79:3b:45:c4:
     7c:ad:cb:47:6d:8e:82:cc:dd:8e:2d:86:fc:94:4b:bf:9d:8e:
     37:37:90:1c:74:73:f1:93:e7:f1:c9:e3:e0:d9:5c:fb:d6:3d:
     09:6b:d5:45:ab:47:d2:65:69:6c:af:81:08:35:6c:87:7f:dd:
     fa:26:2e:8a:bf:4e:53:c1:70:1a:0a:e1:7f:e9:18:c5:82:f1:
     90:9e:6c:29:7b:b7:cc:a3:25:3f:7f:8d:f3:b5:58:25:62:56:
     64:50:43:b3
```

output for `openssl s_client -connect node.foobar.com:8082 -tls1 -servername node.foobar.com`:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
3073997000:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1262:SSL alert number 40
3073997000:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:598:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1433377982
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

I tried `openssl s_client -connect node.foobar.com:8082 -tls1_2 -servername node.foobar.com`, and here is the answer I got :

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
3074009288:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1262:SSL alert number 40
3074009288:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:598:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1433466977
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

By the way, in order to keep the server up, it runs with the forever package (v0.14.1).

Available ciphers :

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:SRP-DSS-AES-256-CBC-SHA:SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA:SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA:ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:SRP-DSS-AES-128-CBC-SHA:SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA:SRP-AES-128-CBC-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA:DHE-DSS-SEED-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA:DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA:ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES128-SHA:SEED-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:IDEA-CBC-SHA:PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:ECDH-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5:PSK-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:SRP-DSS-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA:SRP-RSA-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA:SRP-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA:EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA:DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5:EXP-RC4-MD5
```

Output for `openssl s_client -connect node.foobar.com:8082 -tls1 -cipher "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384" -servername node.foobar.com`

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
3073722568:error:140830B5:SSL routines:SSL3_CLIENT_HELLO:no ciphers     available:s3_clnt.c:757:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1433512430
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

By the way, as a subsidiary question, except for the http becoming a     https for the request of the socket.io/socket.io.js file I have to get in     order to create the connection, is there anything else I will have to change to be able to use this package on my website?

Thank you.

Comment: `openssl s_client -connect my.url.com:8082 -tls1 -servername my.url.com` times out. It appears there is no server listening. Can you verify you have a server listening on that port?

Comment: I seem to have triggered a filter after hitting `node.inkive.com:8082` twice. I now immediately get `connect: Connection refused`. It looks like something is listening on the port, but its *not* talking HTTP or HTTPS. If you are not banned, try `s_client` with `-tls1_2`. I know `-ssl3` and `tls1` does not work.

Answer (score 7):

Here's what's going on.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect node.inkive.com:8082 -tls1 -servername node.inkive.com -cipher 'HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!PSK:!SRP:!MD5:!RC4' -debug
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x7fbb02c23bb0 [0x7fbb0301cc03] (220 bytes => 220 (0xDC))
0000 - 16 03 01 00 d7 01 00 00-d3 03 01 1e 9d af 6b 4b   ..............kK
0010 - ea d5 6c 84 44 b0 13 c5-77 ad 3c 98 4a 50 b3 19   ..l.D...w.<.JP..
0020 - 5c 84 d4 5e ae 58 dc 76-61 f0 9f 00 00 42 c0 14   \..^.X.va....B..
0030 - c0 0a 00 39 00 38 00 37-00 36 00 88 00 87 00 86   ...9.8.7.6......
0040 - 00 85 c0 0f c0 05 c0 13-c0 09 00 33 00 32 00 31   ...........3.2.1
0050 - 00 30 00 45 00 44 00 43-00 42 c0 0e c0 04 c0 12   .0.E.D.C.B......
0060 - c0 08 00 16 00 13 00 10-00 0d c0 0d c0 03 00 ff   ................
0070 - 02 01 00 00 67 00 00 00-14 00 12 00 00 0f 6e 6f   ....g.........no
0080 - 64 65 2e 69 6e 6b 69 76-65 2e 63 6f 6d 00 0b 00   de.inkive.com...
0090 - 04 03 00 01 02 00 0a 00-3a 00 38 00 0e 00 0d 00   ........:.8.....
00a0 - 19 00 1c 00 0b 00 0c 00-1b 00 18 00 09 00 0a 00   ................
00b0 - 1a 00 16 00 17 00 08 00-06 00 07 00 14 00 15 00   ................
00c0 - 04 00 05 00 12 00 13 00-01 00 02 00 03 00 0f 00   ................
00d0 - 10 00 11 00 23 00 00 00-0f 00 01 01               ....#.......
read from 0x7fbb02c23bb0 [0x7fbb03018603] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 15 03 01 00 02                                    .....
read from 0x7fbb02c23bb0 [0x7fbb03018608] (2 bytes => 2 (0x2))
0000 - 02 28                                             .(
140735193977308:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1461:SSL alert number 40
140735193977308:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:645
```

The read of `15 03 01 00 02` is a TLS Record. Its what carries the TLS payload. The `03 01` is the TLS version. The `00 02` is the length of the payload.

The next two bytes are the payload, which is the alert. `02` is the alert, and `28` is the alert number, which is 40.

Alert 40 is [Handshake Failure](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-6). According to [RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) it is sent:

> 7.4.1.3.  Server Hello
>
> When this message will be sent:
>
> ```
>   The server will send this message in response to a ClientHello
>   message when it was able to find an acceptable set of algorithms.
>   If it cannot find such a match, it will respond with a handshake
>   failure alert.
> ```

I hate to answer a question with a question, but what protocols and cipher suites are enabled at the server?

---

Related, the [node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) create a HTTPS server like this:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/the/certificates/cert-test/srv.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/the/certificates/cert-test/crt.pem'),
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8082);
```

You should probably try it since its the official way to create one. The `function(request, response){...}).listen(8082)` looks odd to me.

---

From the ***Edit***:

> Available ciphers :
>
> ```
> ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:...
> ... EXP-EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5:EXP-RC4-MD5
> ```

Use `"HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!MD5:!RC4:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS:!DSA"`. It will get you Integer and Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman, and avoid the [Obsolete Cryptography Warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30280742/608639) in browsers.

Also, don't enable SRP and PSK unless you are actually using them. Don't enable `DSS` unless you have a DSS/DSA key. And you need `aNULL` because anonymous protocols are enabled by default in OpenSSL. And don't enable those export grade cipher suites (`EXP`). And don't enable `MEDIUM` or `LOW` for that matter. All modern user agents have no trouble with `HIGH`.

Using the string above, here are the ciphers you are enabling:

```
$ openssl ciphers -v 'HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!MD5:!RC4:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS:!DSA'
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DH-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DH-RSA-AES256-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DH-DSS-AES256-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DH-RSA-AES256-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DH-DSS-AES256-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
DH-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
DH-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DH-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DH-RSA-AES128-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DH-DSS-AES128-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DH-RSA-AES128-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DH-DSS-AES128-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
DH-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
DH-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
DH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
DH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
```

Comment: How could I check which protocols are enabled? I didn't delete any. I can add the set of ciphers that are present on the server if you want.

Comment: By the way, I change the server's code to be like the one from node.js documentation, but so far, the problem remains the same : I'm unable to create a proper connection.

Comment: @Clément - *" but so far, the problem remains the same..."* - OK, so it appears your problem is much deeper. First, paste the cipher suite string list. Second, how is Node.js built with OpenSSL support?

Comment: I added the cipher suite on my original post. I don't really get your question regarding node.js and openssl, but I suppose you might have your answer there (as _https_ is a subclass of _tls_) <https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html>. It seems to say that nodejs does not enable SSLv2 and SSLv3 by default.

Comment: I'm back to *connection refused*: `openssl s_client -connect node.inkive.com:8082 -tls1 -cipher "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384" -servername node.inkive.com` Can you run it?

Comment: *"I don't really get your question regarding node.js..."* - How did you get Node.js? Did you download a `*.dmg` or tarball? Did you build it yourself? If so, how did you link OpenSSL? What is the platform, and what version of OpenSSL does it supply. Something smells very fishy here....

Comment: @Clément - I can't even connect to the main site on 443. That server looks misconfigured. Can you try another Node.js server on a different machine?

Comment: The server was a bitnami instance on AWS, pre-configured. It runs on Ubuntu 12.04, and OpenSSL is 1.0.1i. It correspond to this kind of instance : https://bitnami.com/stack/nodejs/cloud/amazon ; except that I upgraded it.

Answer (score 0):

just want to remind you that there is no response.writeHeader() method, it should be response.writeHead().
ref:https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_statusmessage_headers

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I corrected it out, but I suppose it will not resolve my problem here...

Answer (score 0):

If the client isn't affected, you might want to do

```
const tls = require('tls')
tls.DEFAULT_ECDH_CURVE = 'auto'
```

somewhere, for example in server.js (your file).
This will only affect the server module and not go to the client at all.

Regarding security, as far as I understood the 8.x.x release accidentally shipped a strict setting for curves (but not the most secure one), and they can't change the default until 10.x.x because of LTS/semver reasons.

In 10.x.x it is 'auto' so I doubt that's a very insecure option.