# OpenSSL ClientHello fails in latest version

Tags: ssl, openssl

I need to connect to an SSL server. When I connect using OpenSSL 1.0.1r it works fine:

```
CONNECTED(00000304)
write to 0x6e13e8 [0x730a98] (297 bytes => 297 (0x129))
0000 - 16 03 01 01 24 01 00 01-20 03 03 16 f2 71 5f 26   ....$... ....q_&
0010 - a5 9b 64 cb 8f 0b 27 65-8d a3 54 e6 de a5 18 7a   ..d...'e..T....z
0020 - 3c 5a e4 08 ab ff 6a 92-d7 45 f3 00 00 8a c0 30   <Z....j..E.....0
0030 - c0 2c c0 28 c0 24 c0 14-c0 0a 00 a3 00 9f 00 6b   .,.(.$.........k
0040 - 00 6a 00 39 00 38 00 88-00 87 c0 32 c0 2e c0 2a   .j.9.8.....2...*
0050 - c0 26 c0 0f c0 05 00 9d-00 3d 00 35 00 84 c0 2f   .&.......=.5.../
0060 - c0 2b c0 27 c0 23 c0 13-c0 09 00 a2 00 9e 00 67   .+.'.#.........g
0070 - 00 40 00 33 00 32 00 9a-00 99 00 45 00 44 c0 31   .@.3.2.....E.D.1
0080 - c0 2d c0 29 c0 25 c0 0e-c0 04 00 9c 00 3c 00 2f   .-.).%.......<./
0090 - 00 96 00 41 00 07 c0 11-c0 07 c0 0c c0 02 00 05   ...A............
00a0 - 00 04 c0 12 c0 08 00 16-00 13 c0 0d c0 03 00 0a   ................
00b0 - 00 15 00 12 00 09 00 ff-01 00 00 6d 00 0b 00 04   ...........m....
00c0 - 03 00 01 02 00 0a 00 34-00 32 00 0e 00 0d 00 19   .......4.2......
00d0 - 00 0b 00 0c 00 18 00 09-00 0a 00 16 00 17 00 08   ................
00e0 - 00 06 00 07 00 14 00 15-00 04 00 05 00 12 00 13   ................
00f0 - 00 01 00 02 00 03 00 0f-00 10 00 11 00 23 00 00   .............#..
0100 - 00 0d 00 20 00 1e 06 01-06 02 06 03 05 01 05 02   ... ............
0110 - 05 03 04 01 04 02 04 03-03 01 03 02 03 03 02 01   ................
0120 - 02 02 02 03 00 0f 00 01-01                        .........
>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0124], ClientHello
    01 00 01 20 03 03 16 f2 71 5f 26 a5 9b 64 cb 8f
    0b 27 65 8d a3 54 e6 de a5 18 7a 3c 5a e4 08 ab
    ff 6a 92 d7 45 f3 00 00 8a c0 30 c0 2c c0 28 c0
    24 c0 14 c0 0a 00 a3 00 9f 00 6b 00 6a 00 39 00
    38 00 88 00 87 c0 32 c0 2e c0 2a c0 26 c0 0f c0
    05 00 9d 00 3d 00 35 00 84 c0 2f c0 2b c0 27 c0
    23 c0 13 c0 09 00 a2 00 9e 00 67 00 40 00 33 00
    32 00 9a 00 99 00 45 00 44 c0 31 c0 2d c0 29 c0
    25 c0 0e c0 04 00 9c 00 3c 00 2f 00 96 00 41 00
    07 c0 11 c0 07 c0 0c c0 02 00 05 00 04 c0 12 c0
    08 00 16 00 13 c0 0d c0 03 00 0a 00 15 00 12 00
    09 00 ff 01 00 00 6d 00 0b 00 04 03 00 01 02 00
    0a 00 34 00 32 00 0e 00 0d 00 19 00 0b 00 0c 00
    18 00 09 00 0a 00 16 00 17 00 08 00 06 00 07 00
    14 00 15 00 04 00 05 00 12 00 13 00 01 00 02 00
    03 00 0f 00 10 00 11 00 23 00 00 00 0d 00 20 00
    1e 06 01 06 02 06 03 05 01 05 02 05 03 04 01 04
    02 04 03 03 01 03 02 03 03 02 01 02 02 02 03 00
    0f 00 01 01
read from 0x6e13e8 [0x735ff8] (7 bytes => 7 (0x7))
0000 - 16 03 03 00 57 02                                 ....W.
0007 - <SPACES/NULS>
read from 0x6e13e8 [0x736002] (85 bytes => 85 (0x55))
0000 - 00 53 03 03 56 bb 11 21-1a ac 49 84 2d be 94 ad   .S..V..!..I.-...
0010 - a0 c4 57 46 bc 70 d0 84-95 ce 96 c6 8c 92 07 2e   ..WF.p..........
0020 - 4e 13 d6 f3 20 aa d7 86-ca 48 5e 01 a1 8c d3 f1   N... ....H^.....
0030 - d7 74 f9 2c 84 48 7d c1-95 6d 22 81 ff 53 ab d3   .t.,.H}..m"..S..
0040 - 0c 89 81 7d a2 00 3d 00-00 0b 00 0b 00 02 01 00   ...}..=.........
0050 - ff 01 00 01                                       ....
0055 - <SPACES/NULS>
<<< TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0057], ServerHello
    02 00 00 53 03 03 56 bb 11 21 1a ac 49 84 2d be
    94 ad a0 c4 57 46 bc 70 d0 84 95 ce 96 c6 8c 92
    07 2e 4e 13 d6 f3 20 aa d7 86 ca 48 5e 01 a1 8c
    d3 f1 d7 74 f9 2c 84 48 7d c1 95 6d 22 81 ff 53
    ab d3 0c 89 81 7d a2 00 3d 00 00 0b 00 0b 00 02
    01 00 ff 01 00 01 00
read from 0x6e13e8 [0x735ffb] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
// etc.
```

However when I connect using OpenSSL 1.0.2f, the server closes the connection immediately:

```
CONNECTED(00000300)
write to 0x7812d0 [0x7ceef0] (317 bytes => 317 (0x13D))
0000 - 16 03 01 01 38 01 00 01-34 03 03 45 1c 09 c2 2e   ....8...4..E....
0010 - 46 06 85 a1 01 fd 0a 2c-bb 6f 15 10 42 74 b3 bf   F......,.o..Bt..
0020 - 9f 2e 5c 00 9f f2 93 8e-c0 18 9c 00 00 b6 c0 30   ..\............0
0030 - c0 2c c0 28 c0 24 c0 14-c0 0a 00 a5 00 a3 00 a1   .,.(.$..........
0040 - 00 9f 00 6b 00 6a 00 69-00 68 00 39 00 38 00 37   ...k.j.i.h.9.8.7
0050 - 00 36 00 88 00 87 00 86-00 85 c0 32 c0 2e c0 2a   .6.........2...*
0060 - c0 26 c0 0f c0 05 00 9d-00 3d 00 35 00 84 c0 2f   .&.......=.5.../
0070 - c0 2b c0 27 c0 23 c0 13-c0 09 00 a4 00 a2 00 a0   .+.'.#..........
0080 - 00 9e 00 67 00 40 00 3f-00 3e 00 33 00 32 00 31   ...g.@.?.>.3.2.1
0090 - 00 30 00 9a 00 99 00 98-00 97 00 45 00 44 00 43   .0.........E.D.C
00a0 - 00 42 c0 31 c0 2d c0 29-c0 25 c0 0e c0 04 00 9c   .B.1.-.).%......
00b0 - 00 3c 00 2f 00 96 00 41-00 07 c0 11 c0 07 c0 0c   .<./...A........
00c0 - c0 02 00 05 00 04 c0 12-c0 08 00 16 00 13 00 10   ................
00d0 - 00 0d c0 0d c0 03 00 0a-00 15 00 12 00 0f 00 0c   ................
00e0 - 00 09 00 ff 01 00 00 55-00 0b 00 04 03 00 01 02   .......U........
00f0 - 00 0a 00 1c 00 1a 00 17-00 19 00 1c 00 1b 00 18   ................
0100 - 00 1a 00 16 00 0e 00 0d-00 0b 00 0c 00 09 00 0a   ................
0110 - 00 23 00 00 00 0d 00 20-00 1e 06 01 06 02 06 03   .#..... ........
0120 - 05 01 05 02 05 03 04 01-04 02 04 03 03 01 03 02   ................
0130 - 03 03 02 01 02 02 02 03-00 0f 00 01 01            .............
>>> TLS 1.2  [length 0005]
    16 03 01 01 38
>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0138], ClientHello
    01 00 01 34 03 03 45 1c 09 c2 2e 46 06 85 a1 01
    fd 0a 2c bb 6f 15 10 42 74 b3 bf 9f 2e 5c 00 9f
    f2 93 8e c0 18 9c 00 00 b6 c0 30 c0 2c c0 28 c0
    24 c0 14 c0 0a 00 a5 00 a3 00 a1 00 9f 00 6b 00
    6a 00 69 00 68 00 39 00 38 00 37 00 36 00 88 00
    87 00 86 00 85 c0 32 c0 2e c0 2a c0 26 c0 0f c0
    05 00 9d 00 3d 00 35 00 84 c0 2f c0 2b c0 27 c0
    23 c0 13 c0 09 00 a4 00 a2 00 a0 00 9e 00 67 00
    40 00 3f 00 3e 00 33 00 32 00 31 00 30 00 9a 00
    99 00 98 00 97 00 45 00 44 00 43 00 42 c0 31 c0
    2d c0 29 c0 25 c0 0e c0 04 00 9c 00 3c 00 2f 00
    96 00 41 00 07 c0 11 c0 07 c0 0c c0 02 00 05 00
    04 c0 12 c0 08 00 16 00 13 00 10 00 0d c0 0d c0
    03 00 0a 00 15 00 12 00 0f 00 0c 00 09 00 ff 01
    00 00 55 00 0b 00 04 03 00 01 02 00 0a 00 1c 00
    1a 00 17 00 19 00 1c 00 1b 00 18 00 1a 00 16 00
    0e 00 0d 00 0b 00 0c 00 09 00 0a 00 23 00 00 00
    0d 00 20 00 1e 06 01 06 02 06 03 05 01 05 02 05
    03 04 01 04 02 04 03 03 01 03 02 03 03 02 01 02
    02 02 03 00 0f 00 01 01
read from 0x7812d0 [0x7d4450] (7 bytes => 0 (0x0))
10124:error:140790E5:SSL routines:ssl23_write:ssl handshake failure:.\ssl\s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 317 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1455100247
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

I don't suppose anyone speaks `ClientHello` sufficiently well to tell me what the difference is, and how to get OpenSSL 1.0.2f to behave like the old version (even if it is insecure; I don't control the server).

I checked both traces with Wireshark, and the only significant differences I can see are that OpenSSL 1.0.2's ClientHello packet is identified as "SSL" by Wireshark, and the record layer is SSL:

[image: OpenSSL 1.0.2]

Whereas OpenSSL 1.0.1 is identified as TLS 1.2. It also has fewer cypher suites (I guess they removed some insecure ones?).

[image: OpenSSL 1.0.1]

I've tried the following combinations, and these are how Wireshark labels them in the "Protocol" column:

- 1.0.1: `<no options>`=TLSv1.2; `-ssl2`=SSLv2; `-ssl3`=SSLv3; `-tls1_2`=TLSv1.2
- 1.0.2: `<no options>`=SSL; `-ssl2`=SSLv2; `-ssl3`=SSLv3; `-tls1_2`=SSL

Any ideas about:

1. Why Wireshark decodes 1.0.1 and 1.0.2 differently?
2. Why the connection is failing with 1.0.2?
3. How I can get OpenSSL 1.0.2 to behave like 1.0.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why Wireshark decodes 1.0.1 and 1.0.2 differently?

See [SSL Record Layer vs SSLv3 Record Layer](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/14419/ssl-record-layer-vs-sslv3-record-layer) on the Wireshark Q&A bulletin board and [Secure Socket Layer (SSL)](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL) on the Wireshark wiki.

> Why the connection is failing with 1.0.2?

Looks like a buggy server that's rejecting a record layer that's not an early one, like one used in SSLv3.

The record layer is just that... It specifies the version of the record layer, which is simply the framing of SSL/TLS protocol messages. It is ***not*** a *`MIN-TLS-VERSION`* as many people think.

The TLS protocol version is just that... It specifies the version of the SSL/TLS protocol. It is ***not*** a *`MAX-TLS-VERSION`* as many people think.

> How I can get OpenSSL 1.0.2 to behave like 1.0.1?

Use the following in your client, but its not exactly the same. The OpenSSL client will do the right thing and select TLS 1.2 if its available:

```
/* Uses the early record layer for downlevel servers */
const SSL_METHOD* method = SSLv23_method();
if(NULL == method) handleFailure();

ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
if(ctx == NULL) handleFailure();

/* Cannot fail ??? */
const long flags = SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1 | SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1 | SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION;
SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, flags);
```

I checked OpenSSL 1.0.2's `ssl/ssl.h`, and both `SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1` and `SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1` are available.

There's a different way to do it for OpenSSL Master (a.k.a, OpenSSL 1.1.0 and above); see [Working around servers requiring SSL 2/3 record layer, and using TLS 1.2?](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2016-February/002986.html)

---

> ... [OpenSSL 1.0.2] also has fewer cipher suites (I guess they removed some insecure ones?).

You should *not* leave cipher suites to chance. You should do something like the following:

```
const char* const PREFERRED_CIPHERS = "HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!PSK:!SRP:!MD5:!RC4";
res = SSL_set_cipher_list(ssl, PREFERRED_CIPHERS);
if(res != 1) handleFailure();
```

The `!PSK` and `!SRP` simply removes cipher suites that are not usually used. `!MD5` and `!RC4` are removed for servers to help avoid the [Obsolete cryptography warning from Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30270788).

You could even do the following:

```
const char* const PREFERRED_CIPHERS =
    "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:"
    "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:"
    "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:"
    "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:"
    "DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:"
    "DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:"
    "DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:"
    "DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256";

res = SSL_set_cipher_list(ssl, PREFERRED_CIPHERS);
if(res != 1) handleFailure();
```

Be sure to always offer a AES/GCM cipher suite because as server configurations move to a TLS 1.2-only configuration, that's the cipher suite they usually choose.

Also, each cipher suite takes up to bytes in the `ClientHello`, and you want to *minimize* the number of them. You want to minimize them because some older Proxies and Interception boxes use a fixed size buffer for the client's `ClientHello`, and they can't handle the proliferation of cipher suite options available in TLS 1.2. The older boxes include F5 and Ironport middleware.

Answer (score 0):

> Why Wireshark decodes 1.0.1 and 1.0.2 differently?

No idea.

> Why the connection is failing with 1.0.2?

Hard to tell but I've seen several servers having problems with some ciphers added to OpenSSL 1.0.2 or that too much ciphers were given or similar. I've seen similar problems with recent LibreSSL versions. In this case the servers have obviously broken TLS stacks.

> How I can get OpenSSL 1.0.2 to behave like 1.0.1?

You can try to reduce the cipher set so that it only uses the same ciphers as OpenSSL 1.0.1. Notable I've seen servers croak  ChaCha20-Poly1305 was inside the cipher set, probably they did not understand what kind of cipher this is.